# (Python) Dictionary Within a list gives "IndexError: list index out of range" error

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, web-scraping

```
[{'url': '/apartments/san-francisco-ca/923-folsom/5Yy6Np/'}, {'url': 'https://www.zillow.com/apartments/san-francisco-ca/the-brady/C4XYzK/'}, {'url': 'https://www.zillow.com/apartments/san-francisco-ca/northpoint-apartments/5XjLPJ/'}, {'url': 'https://www.zillow.com/b/747-geary-street-oakland-ca-CYzGVt/'}, {'url': '/apartments/san-francisco-ca/edgewater/5XjVQc/'}, {'url': '/apartments/san-francisco-ca/1188-mission-at-trinity-place/5XjN4q/'}]
```

this is the self.results files output, its a list, len gives 6 elements, I want to reach the 'url' inside the dictionary

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import time
params={
    'searchQueryState': '{"mapBounds":{"north":42.009517,"east":-114.131253,"south":32.528832,"west":-124.482045},"mapZoom":5,"isMapVisible":true,"filterState":{"price":{"max":872627},"beds":{"min":1},"fore":{"value":false},"mp":{"max":3000},"auc":{"value":false},"nc":{"value":false},"fr":{"value":true},"fsbo":{"value":false},"cmsn":{"value":false},"fsba":{"value":false}},"isListVisible":true,"regionSelection":[{"regionId":9,"regionType":2}],"usersSearchTerm":"California","schoolId":null}'
 }



class ZillowScraper():
    results=[]
    headers= {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
    'Cookie':'zguid=24|%249e975354-f675-419d-88e1-268640260ac4; _ga=GA1.2.124390097.1686931595; zjs_anonymous_id=%229e975354-f675-419d-88e1-268640260ac4%22; zg_anonymous_id=%2262a63b50-344d-4671-880c-04d453844549%22; _pxvid=c4d5254a-0c5f-11ee-9b64-15b9a4b973bd; _gcl_au=1.1.80251162.1686931598; __pdst=38dc54a14928440ea9e18bce80e1ec08; _fbp=fb.1.1686931597756.1157135805; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU9EVXhZelF4WmpZdE4yWXhNaTAwTTJReUxUaGhZVEl0TlRaak1tRXpZamxsTldWbA; g_state={"i_l":0}; userid=X|3|3dbd58da0e59b75f%7C2%7Cq9T-1RNvuHMHNFQyWSbr7sl7mTb0P-i9btbmtnsodtE%3D; loginmemento=1|2fd5fb94fc32e42f5344da80f8f13e75986fad0f163b2c5704da1ff0eae2afb6; zjs_user_id=%22X1-ZUrfq9bm176tc9_1zmzs%22; JSESSIONID=973ED705C2EDB91A7BF10D85CDFF5814; zgsession=1|3c6828c5-3e67-4639-9972-fd4736403a62; ZILLOW_SID=1|AAAAAVVbFRIBVVsVEjg1bj1MjO6GG9oxT7XzrfvIXY2RKMzKEvaz6DaBCZtWJSCGtWGKfElpHr957F4KqyLOxAtmIUA1BizCKg; _gid=GA1.2.1380352076.1688718740; pxcts=ca98aaaa-1ca0-11ee-b480-616f51557753; DoubleClickSession=true; _clck=1uqa94j|2|fd3|0|1262; tfpsi=dcb016eb-2d99-44e8-a777-9a8a6050caaf; _uetsid=333808901ca211eeab4a1f19a5284c94; _uetvid=c5ebbf500c5f11eeb6c3c9c655f631e0; _px3=9c5cade37141a8e60d6380f6a9cfb3c9330d4e390ed91edd6b011cb63e92933d:d7C2qYwntLRbpcZy/DTjqpGCduzy+AH7I9u+VkVNCzM4wMXrOL7OP2R//DfgEP1kRn1hrxo8uUkl8Opv4tdx3w==:1000:cS+n8Og6wNAKCZwozMRKoLCCrdTzCbVArgT+vhD5SwsRuMYxwoRCaJL7Y1Y8iIp2j1ARVrm9eNWUlJykb5sPuC1PxrsMJodXAyq9y7PFy4qFgv5GdyFWvmV0E2asllfSbIp15P9L4sGP8A+qTuFB5snLuOo5NWZidGglE+KYRQx0gieWD2BkI4BQjN3DnrU1bJRUa9+omJnH1zphmhIJ4w==; __gads=ID=0789e8e54f1dec08:T=1686931597:RT=1688720215:S=ALNI_MaqX2esiAR8pEZ2TAX0dGHUBNSrdA; __gpi=UID=00000c2fceeb5fe3:T=1686931597:RT=1688720215:S=ALNI_MaGvh-b1S5JJXngtBs3-TQBlDKz_w; _gat=1; _clsk=1gz2p94|1688720278842|12|0|s.clarity.ms/collect; AWSALB=MKF/saKP1r0geqVVfYxmvBt8BXaElPu2UvRc+unjgOvJ0lVSdn2+oATj6UI10oWkuLKOz9thWJZkdY+XiON9bnmZojeR0r3c11rEA6oSYhi1bOO/QS35UIMVD83K; AWSALBCORS=MKF/saKP1r0geqVVfYxmvBt8BXaElPu2UvRc+unjgOvJ0lVSdn2+oATj6UI10oWkuLKOz9thWJZkdY+XiON9bnmZojeR0r3c11rEA6oSYhi1bOO/QS35UIMVD83K; search=6|1691312278512%7Crect%3D42.009517%252C-114.131253%252C32.528832%252C-124.482045%26rid%3D9%26disp%3Dmap%26mdm%3Dauto%26p%3D1%26z%3D0%26listPriceActive%3D1%26beds%3D1-%26price%3D0-872627%26mp%3D0-3000%26fs%3D0%26fr%3D1%26mmm%3D0%26rs%3D0%26ah%3D0%26singlestory%3D0%26housing-connector%3D0%26abo%3D0%26garage%3D0%26pool%3D0%26ac%3D0%26waterfront%3D0%26finished%3D0%26unfinished%3D0%26cityview%3D0%26mountainview%3D0%26parkview%3D0%26waterview%3D0%26hoadata%3D1%26zillow-owned%3D0%263dhome%3D0%26featuredMultiFamilyBuilding%3D0%26excludeNullAvailabilityDates%3D0%26commuteMode%3Ddriving%26commuteTimeOfDay%3Dnow%09%09%09%7B%22isList%22%3Atrue%2C%22isMap%22%3Atrue%7D%09%09%09%09%09',

    'Sec-Ch-Ua':'"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile':'?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform':'"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36}'
    }
    
    def fetch(self,url,params):
        response = requests.get(url,headers=self.headers, params=params)
        print(response)
        return response

    def parse(self, response):
        content = BeautifulSoup(response,features='html.parser')
        deck = content.find('ul', {'class': 'List-c11n-8-89-0__sc-1smrmqp-0 StyledSearchListWrapper-srp__sc-1ieen0c-0 kZyCWU fgiidE photo-cards'})
        for card in deck.contents[0]:
            script = card.find('script',{'type': 'application/ld+json'})
            if script:
                
                script_json = json.loads(script.contents)
                print(script_json)
                try:
                    self.results.append({
                        'latitude': script_json['geo']['latitude'],
                        'longtitude': script_json['json']['longtitude'],
                        'context': script_json['floorSize']['value'],
                        'url': script_json['url']
                    })
                except KeyError:
                    self.results.append({
                        'url': script_json['url']
                        
                    })
                print(script_json['url'])
                
            
            else:
                article= card.find('article',{'role':'presentation'})
                if article is None:
                    continue
                else:
                    script=article.find('address',{'data-test':'property-card-addr'})
                    if script:
                        print(script.prettify())
                        pass
                    else:
                        return
            print(self.results)
            #print(type(self.results[0]))
            print(self.results)
            #if "http" not in self.results[0]{'url'}:
               # self.results[-1]{'url'}=f"https://zillow.com{self.results[0]{'url'}}" 
            print(self.results)
            
    def run(self):
        url="https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/rentals/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22north%22%3A37.88007392999709%2C%22east%22%3A-122.09541072195475%2C%22south%22%3A37.59118324417655%2C%22west%22%3A-122.823254960236%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22California%22%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A20330%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A872627%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22mp%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A3000%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D"
        params={
            'searchQueryState': '{"mapBounds":{"north":42.009517,"east":-114.131253,"south":32.528832,"west":-124.482045},"mapZoom":5,"isMapVisible":true,"filterState":{"price":{"max":872627},"beds":{"min":1},"fore":{"value":false},"mp":{"max":3000},"auc":{"value":false},"nc":{"value":false},"fr":{"value":true},"fsbo":{"value":false},"cmsn":{"value":false},"fsba":{"value":false}},"isListVisible":true,"regionSelection":[{"regionId":9,"regionType":2}],"usersSearchTerm":"California","schoolId":null}'
            }
        res= self.fetch(url,params)
        self.parse(res.text)

if __name__== '__main__':
    scraper = ZillowScraper()
    scraper.run()
```

I tried to reach to the dictionary and extract the url elements content to compare with my  own desired http values but couldn't get the indexes altough the type is a list and it involves 6 elements.

Edit I tried to post the full code but indentation problems occur altough I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Kubilay
> Kaan\Documents\Dev_Projects\python_projects\Python_Sketchs\zillow_class_oriented.py",
> line 89, in <module>
>     scraper.run()   File "C:\Users\Kubilay Kaan\Documents\Dev_Projects\python_projects\Python_Sketchs\zillow_class_oriented.py",
> line 85, in run
>     self.parse(res.text)   File "C:\Users\Kubilay Kaan\Documents\Dev_Projects\python_projects\Python_Sketchs\zillow_class_oriented.py",
> line 73, in parse
>     print(type(self.results[0])) IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I dont know if this helps, but this turns the list of dictionaries into a flat list of urls: `urls = [dct["url"] for dct in list_of_dicts]`

Comment: @9769953 I did it

Comment: change `script.contents[0]` to `script.contents` and see what are you are getting.

Comment: Is `def run` really inside the `for` loop? Why?

Comment: You'll get this error if `self.results` is empty, which will happen when `if script:` fails.

Comment: @Barmar no it's under the class indentation, but I cant post the full code ctrl K doesnt work

Comment: @Barmar  raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list when I delete the 0

Comment: self.results give me [{'url': '/apartments/san-francisco-ca/923-folsom/5Yy6Np/'}, {'url':
'https://www.zillow.com/apartments/san-francisco-ca/the-brady/C4XYzK/'},
{'url':
'https://www.zillow.com/apartments/san-francisco-ca/northpoint-apartments/5XjLPJ/'},
{'url':
'https://www.zillow.com/b/747-geary-street-oakland-ca-CYzGVt/'},
{'url': '/apartments/san-francisco-ca/edgewater/5XjVQc/'}, {'url':
'/apartments/san-francisco-ca/1188-mission-at-trinity-place/5XjN4q/'}] i have no problem with reaching the content

Comment: I don't understand what your second response to me is about. I didn't suggest any changes that would cause a TypeError. Was that about Zero's suggestion?

Comment: Oh my bad @Barmar, it was a reply to Zero, I could add all my code into it now you can check it out again if it didn't make sense at first, and the problem got solved with the answer below, I specially thank you for your efforts while I try my best adapt the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access dictionary values within a list, but there may be a problem with your indexing method. Based on your code, if you want to access each 'url' value in the dictionaries stored in self.results, you should loop through self.results.

Below is an example on how you can access 'url' in the dictionaries and modify it if 'http' is not in 'url':

```
for result in self.results:          #'result' is a dict and 'results' are a list
    if "http" not in result['url']:  # here 'result' is a dictionary
        result['url'] = f"https://www.zillow.com{result['url']}"
```

This code block loops through each dictionary in self.results (list) and checks whether 'http' is part of the 'url' value. If not, it prepends the 'url' with "https://www.zillow.com". Please note that this will directly modify self.results. The changes are made in place, meaning the original self.results is changed. If you need the original data, consider making a copy before you make changes.  I think you may have mistakenly used curly braces to try access the key of the dict. Use square brackets perhaps.
[image: Syntax error]

You'll need to make sure your url paths are correctly concatenated. If the paths in 'url' start with '/', you might end up with '//' in your concatenated url. If the paths do not start with '/', your code should work as expected.

I also sometimes use the .get() method to get items from a json object if the normal indexing doesn't work. Example:

```
car = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964,
  "price": 10234
}
x = car.get("price")
print(x) # should return 10234 as integer.
```

Also, I've noticed you've struggled to nicely format the code.  You can click the curly braces button in the Stack Overflow editor to format code to a code block format (4 spaces added before each line, then Stack Overflow knows to put everything into a code block for nicer display).
[image]

Comment: Glad it worked! Nice day to you too.